# TypeError: players.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following JSON array :-

```
    [
{"A":"Player","B":"Position","C":"Age","D":"Acc","E":"Wor","F":"Vis","G":"Tec","H":"Tea","I":"Tck","J":"Str","K":"Sta","L":"Pos","M":"Pen","N":"Pas","O":"Pac","P":"OtB","Q":"Nat","R":"Mar","S":"L Th","T":"Lon","U":"Ldr","V":"Jum","W":"Hea","X":"Fre","Y":"Fla","Z":"Fir","AA":"Fin","AB":"Dri","AC":"Det","AD":"Dec","AE":"Cro","AF":"Cor","AG":"Cnt","AH":"Cmp","AI":"Bra","AJ":"Bal","AK":"Ant","AL":"Agi","AM":"Agg"},
{"A":"Cyril Ruffier_YP22I ","B":"AM (R), ST (C)","C":"23","D":"14","E":"13","F":"12","G":"11","H":"14","I":"4","J":"13","K":"13","L":"8","M":"8","N":"11","O":"13","P":"15","Q":"8","R":"2","S":"4","T":"8","U":"12","V":"13","W":"8","X":"7","Y":"11","Z":"16","AA":"9","AB":"10","AC":"17","AD":"12","AE":"9","AF":"5","AG":"8","AH":"13","AI":"4","AJ":"18","AK":"10","AL":"11","AM":"7"},
{"A":"John Latouchent_YP26B ","B":"M (L), AM (RLC), ST (C)","C":"19","D":"15","E":"14","F":"10","G":"13","H":"14","I":"4","J":"10","K":"13","L":"12","M":"4","N":"13","O":"13","P":"12","Q":"11","R":"9","S":"4","T":"7","U":"10","V":"9","W":"9","X":"9","Y":"14","Z":"9","AA":"8","AB":"11","AC":"14","AD":"9","AE":"10","AF":"8","AG":"9","AH":"10","AI":"9","AJ":"17","AK":"11","AL":"14","AM":"12"}
]
```

and I am trying to map it so that I can display it in this component:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { getStickyState } from './Utils';

const PlayersDisplay = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = getStickyState([], 'players');

  return (
    <>
      {players && (
        <div className='attributesDisplay-container'>
          <div className='container'>
            {console.log(players)};
            {players.map((player) => {
              return <div>{player}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PlayersDisplay;
```

This is my getStickyState function in my Utils component:-

```
export function getStickyState(defaultValue, key) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

    if (stickyValue !== null) {
      setValue(JSON.parse(stickyValue));
    }
  }, [key]);

  return [value, setValue];
}
```

and this is the setStickyState :-

```
export function setStickyState(defaultValue, key) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}
```

The console.log is outputting the JSON array I posted here.

However players.map is throwing the error .map is not a function.  I also tried JSON.parse(players) but to no avail.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hmm.. couldn't see anything that is glaringly wrong with the code.. what happens if you log the first element of players.. so instead of console.log(players); do console.log(players[0]);

Comment: Are you sure `players` returns an array? Also what does `getStickyState` look like under the hood?

Comment: Gonna need more info and a sandbox most likely. If `players` is indeed an array, then `.map` would work. You said you have that array, where is it? How is it loaded into the state via `getStickyState` (and what does that hook do)? Also JSON.parse is for parsing JSON, not a plain old regular array.

Comment: Added the getStickyState function.  The JSON array I displayed is from the console.log, so players is populated with that Array, that is why I am confused.

Comment: @GlenK console.log(players[0]) displays '[' only

Comment: I think what's being displayed is the string representation of the array.. that is why players[0] is printing "["... so you need to fix how the players is being constructed or returned..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`players` is a string, not an array, seeing as `console.log(players[0])` displays '['. I don't know why, from the code, since you call JSON.parse. Perhaps you have saved the players array incorrectly to localstorage, for example by using JSON.stringify twice. We don't have the code you used to store the data to localstorage.

Comment: Ok is there a way to change this to a JSON then?  I do not know if there is another way to save to localstorage, I would normally save as string to localstorage and then parse it.  Could it be Next.js since it is SSR?

Comment: If you called JSON.parse again on players, it would work. However that is a hack obviously. Inspect the stickyValue in useEffect. Is it a double escaped string?

Comment: I added the code where I am setting localstorage.

Comment: It *looks* like `value` is already stringified. Is that possible? Inspect the type of `value` before you JSON,stringify it.

Comment: yes that was the cause.  I removed the JSON stringify on the setItem and it worked!  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answer/upvote if it helped. Cheers.

Comment: Your code is now going to confuse people if getStickyState issues JSON.parse but setStickyState doesn't issue JSON.stringify. I would change the callers of setStickyState to pass objects, not JSON-stringified objects. Or your consumers of getStickyState have to be prepared to JSON.parse the results they get. You should be consistent, either way.

Comment: Yes I will only JSON parse and stringify outside of the set/get StickyState, that's a good suggestion thanks